# Atomically query for all collection documents + watching for further changes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

Our Java app saves its configurations in a MongoDB collections. When the app starts it reads all the configurations from MongoDB and caches them in Maps. We would like to use the change stream API to be able also to watch for updates of the configurations collections. 
So, upon app startup, first we would like to get all configurations, and from now on - watch for any further change.
Is there an easy way to execute the following **atomically**:

1. A `find()` that retrieves all configurations (documents)
2. Start a `watch()` that will send all further updates

By atomically I mean - without potentially missing any update (between 1 and 2 someone could update the collection with new configuration).

Comment: This seems like it would be a common need, very surprised this is not a feature provided by MongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure I lose no update notifications, I found that I can use `watch().startAtOperationTime(serverTime)` (for MongoDB of 4.0 or later), as follows.

1. Query the MongoDB server for its current time, using command such as `Document hostInfoDoc = mongoTemplate.executeCommand(new Document("hostInfo", 1))`
2. Query for all interesting documents: `List<C> configList = mongoTemplate.findAll(clazz);`
3. Extract the server time from hostInfoDoc: `BsonTimestamp serverTime = (BsonTimestamp) hostInfoDoc.get("operationTime");`
4. Start the change stream configured with the saved server time  `ChangeStreamIterable<Document> changes = eventCollection.watch().startAtOperationTime(serverTime);`

Since 1 ends before 2 starts, we know that the documents that were returned by 2 were at least same or fresher than the ones on that server time. And any updates that happened on or after this server time will be sent to us by the change stream (I don't care to run again redundant updates, because I use map as cache, so extra add/remove won't make a difference, as long as the last action arrives).

I think I could also use `watch().resumeAfter(_idOfLastAddedDoc)` (didn't try). I did not use this approach because of the following scenario: the collection is empty, and the first document is added after getting all (none) documents, and before starting the `watch()`. In that scenario I don't have previous document `_id` to use as resume token.

**Update**

Instead of using "hostInfo" for getting the server time, which couldn't be used in our production, I ended using "dbStats" like that:

`Document dbStats= mongoOperations.executeCommand(new Document("dbStats", 1));`
`BsonTimestamp serverTime = (BsonTimestamp) dbStats.get("operationTime");`

Comment: Since you're requesting the serverTime after findAll, isn't there a chance, however small, that a document could have been inserted/modified between the two requests?

Comment: Note that I perform the actual request in 1. At 3 I only extract the serverTime from the returned Document. So the server time was taken and filled in the Document before calling findAll.

Comment: I don't think this method guarantees that all documents will be seen by the findAll, particularly if a new document has just been written (before your timestamp) but has not arrived yet at the mongo node you are querying.  It might work with a single node cluster but it feels like there should be a better solution for this.

Comment: @Phil operationTime maps to the oplog--so it should be fine.  And actually I think the risk now is that you may process the same document twice (once in `findAll` and again in the changestream.